# Why is this function continuous?

Tags: general-topology

I working on the following problem

Pick an $a \in \prod_{i \in I} X_i.$ Let $F \subset I $ be a finite subset of $I$. Define 
$$
X_F = \{ (x_i)_{i \in I} : x_i \in X_i, \text{ and } x_i = a_i \text{ for } i \not \in F \}
$$

Show that $X_F$ is connected if all spaces $X_i$ with $i \in F$are connected.

I considered a map $g:X_{f_1} \times \dots \times X_{f_k} \to X_f$ Which basically takes $a$ and turns the first $f_1, \dots f_k$ coordinates to be the coordinates from an element  in $X_{f_1} \times \dots \times X_{f_k}$. 
$g((x_{f_1}, x_{f_2}, \dots, x_{f_k})) =(\dots,x_{f_1}, x_{f_2}, \dots, x_{f_k}, a_{f_{k+1}}, a_{f_{k+2}}, \dots) $.
Then g is surjective. How can I show that $g$ is also continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Use the characteristic property. A function into a product space is continuous if and only if all the projections are continuous. In this case, the projections are either identity functions (continuous), or constant functions (continuous), so $g$ is continuous.

e: The first few coordinates aren't actually identities, they're projections, but the fact that a projection function is continuous also follows from the characteristic property.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, the projection from $X_{f_{1}} \times \dots$ are either equal to one of the coordinates in $a$ (constant) or one of the whole spaces $X_{f_i}$

Comment: Yes, $\pi_{f_i} \circ g : X_{F} \rightarrow X_{f_i}$ is just $\pi_{f_i} : X_{f_1} \times \dots \times X_{f_k} \rightarrow X_{f_i}$ for appropriate values of $i$. For the other values of $i$, it's just a constant function. Either way, the projections of $g$ are all continuous, so $g$ is continuous.